# \lstMakeShortInline with @ delimiter

Tags: beamer, listings, delimiters

I'm including a fair amount of inline C++ code in a beamer presentation I'm making, and I want to be able to use the short syntax for \lstinline. My code displays fine if I use, for example, the ! character as my delimiter, like

```
\lstMakeShortInline!
!cout << "This C++ displays fine";!
```

But when I try to use the @ character as my delimiter, because it will hardly ever appear in C++ code, the line is displayed unformatted, with literal @s surrounding it. As far as I know, @ is not a special character in LaTeX, so why is this happening?

Edit: I did not test the example I gave, and on further inspection, the *only* character that I can get to work as a delimiter is ~, as demonstrated with this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily]~
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
~cout << "This C++ displays fine";~
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, other delimiters (such as |) seem to work in the article documentclass, is this an issue with beamer?

Comment: Could you please make a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: @percusse what does it do? All I could find is that using it in a macro name usually indicates that it's internal.

Comment: @ is a big deal in TeX. Using `@` creates a name clash with the existing internal macro `\lstMakeShortInline@` and I'm not sure whether it is worth of hacking it such that it works. (defined in `listings.sty` line 1932

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that there was an internal macro sharing that name. But that still doesn't explain why all the other delimiters are broken.

Comment: It works nicely with a standard class such as `article`. It seems `beamer` is doing some catcode stuff. If you make `@` active (``\catcode`\@=\active``) before `\lstMakeShortInline` _and_ between `\begin{document}` and `\begin{frame}` things work as the should

Comment: @cgnieder that works beautifully. Thank you. You ought to make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily]@
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily]|
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\show @
\show |
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

the compilation stops with

```
> the character @.
```

and then with

```
> |=macro:
->\lstinline [language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily ]|.
```

showing the fundamental difference between the two cases: `@` is normalized to have category code 12. This happens at begin document, so you can postpone your declaration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily]|
\begin{document}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=C++,basicstyle=\ttfamily]@

\begin{frame}[fragile]
|cout << "This C++ displays fine";|

@cout << "This C++ displays fine";@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

will display both lines in the same way. Remember to declare `fragile` all frames where verbatim material is typeset.

[image]